# Automapper Map UserId Property By Name to static value

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I use automapper to map models between each user.
I can also do this to map a property of a specific type to a userId

```
  cfg.CreateMap<Model, Command>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => ClaimsPrincipal.Current.UserId))
```

But I can't find a way to make this to some kind of convention so that everytime models are mapped and there is a Property "UserId" it should be set to ClaimsPrincipal.Current.UserId.

Is this now working ?

Any advice?

Comment: Try ForAllPropertyMaps or ForAllMaps.

Comment: do you have an example ? I tried but can't see the right method to use. there is only "UseValue" but i can't set a delegate to a value function there

Comment: It's ResolveUsing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the MapTo Attribute?

```
public class Foo
{
    [MapTo("SourceOfBar")]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I Want to have one global rule so that i dont Need to annotate all Models